# Why pagination with Bootstrap does not work?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, pagination

I was trying to use pagination by following this link:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples (under Pagination)

It just doesn't work properly.
In fact, if I wanted to have only 3 lines on the first page (then I change pageSize by setting it to 3) I get all the lines (4) and not 3.

[image: My Example]

Where did I go wrong? Thanks everyone for the help

ts file

```js
import { Product } from '../product';
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private productservice: ProductService, private fb: FormBuilder, private modalService: NgbModal) {} 

  productsArray: any[] = [];
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  products: Product[] = [];
  product: Product = new Product();
  productlist: any;
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 4;
  collectionSize = 8;


  ngOnInit() {
      this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
          this.products = data;
          this.dtTrigger.next();
          this.refreshProduct();
      })
      this.editProfileForm = this.fb.group({
          productcode: [''],
          name: ['']
      });
  }

  refreshProduct() {
      this.productsArray = this.products
          .map((product: any, i: number) => ({ id: i + 1, ...product }))
          .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
  }
```

html file

```js
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Product code</th>
          <th>Product name</th>
          <th>Product image</th>
          <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
          <td>{{product.productcode}}</td>
          <td>{{product.name}}</td>
          <td class="py-1"><img src="data:image/png;base64"  width="80" height="80"></td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteProduct(product.productcode)" class='btn btn-primary'><i
                class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(editProfileModal, product)" >Update</button>
          </td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody><br>
    </table>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
      <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" (pageChange)="refreshProducts()">
      </ngb-pagination>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this 
.slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
Returns 0 every time you paginating ?

Comment: I don't know this because I'm new. I think the error is there since it doesn't work. What do you suggest me to do eventually? I would not like the error to be in id = i + 1 ... product as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to change products inside ngFor to productsArray.

"products" will always have the full list. you always use "products" to fill "productsArray" depending on your needs, and what you wanna display on the UI.

Comment: right, I had missed it. I thank you so much. A last question. Is it possible to add two buttons that allow me, respectively, to return directly to the first or last page?

Comment: No problem! Yes you definitely can. For example to go to the last: you just need to change page = {yourLastPageIndex} and call refreshProduct.

Comment: OK done. Or I saw that you can add {boundaryLinks] = "true" and automatically they are added to the other buttons that already exist. I noticed a small problem; in the example posted in the link it puts collectionSize = COUNTRIES.length; in order to find the maximum number of elements. I tried to do it myself in my code by putting product.length and it returns 0, in fact I manually put the number 8. How can I correct this last thing?

Comment: after "this.products = data;" put "this.collectionSize=this.products.length"

Comment: always leaving collectionSize = product.length right?

Comment: in fact I wanted a little help. What is the use of putting this.collectionSize = this.products.length? Why do you put it on? Sorry if I ask this question, I'm a beginner

Comment: Yeah I understand, you should try to go over the angular docs in details, experience a sample project to know the basics. collectionSize is used by bootstrap, you just need to assign it the total number of products..

Comment: yes I know what collectionSize is for; I would like to understand what this line is for this.collectionSize = this.products.length?